# CreateProcessA not working or returning any errors

Tags: c++, winapi

I've tried to used both `CreateProcessA` and `CreateProcess` to create a instance of notepad, but to no success. `CreateProcess` always returns an error code of 2 when I run it, but `CreateProccessA` doesn't return anything at all.

This is what I have so far:

```
STARTUPINFOA startInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;

ZeroMemory(&startInfo, sizeof(startInfo));
startInfo.cb = sizeof(startInfo);
ZeroMemory(&processInfo, sizeof(processInfo));

if (CreateProcessA(NULL, NULL,NULL,NULL,FALSE,NULL, NULL, "C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe", &startInfo, &processInfo)) {
    DWORD Error = GetLastError();
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "FAILED", "FAILED", MB_OK);
    printf("%d", Error);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa

Comment: Your success/failure checking is the opposite of what the documentation says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error 2 is `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.  You are passing the path to `notepad.exe` in the `lpCurrentDirectory` parameter, but it needs to be passed in the `lpApplicationName` or `lpCommandLine` parameter instead:

```cpp
CreateProcessA("C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &startInfo, &processInfo)
```

```cpp
CreateProcessA(NULL, "C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe", NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &startInfo, &processInfo)
```

Also, you are calling `GetLastError()` when `CreateProcessA()` is successful.  You need to call it when `CreateProcessA()` fails instead:

```cpp
if (!CreateProcessA(...)) { // <-- note the !
    DWORD Error = GetLastError();
    ...
}
```

Lastly, the `%d` specifier of `printf()` expects an `int`, not a `DWORD`. Use `%ul` instead, which expects an `unsigned long`, which is what [`DWORD` is defined as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types):

```cpp
printf("%ul", Error);
```

Comment: thanks that fixed the notepad problem but how do I create a process that needs administrative privilege's? My original code tried to open a instance of Cheat Engine but even now that I have the lpAppilcation name fixed it doesn't work

Comment: @JacksonSimpson, That's an entirely separate question with its own research involved. Anyone searching for how to do that will never find the answer if it's tucked away in this question.

Comment: @JacksonSimpson `CreateProcess()` cannot create a new process with elevate rights unless the calling process is already elevated, or the launched EXE has a UAC manifest that requires elevation (`requestedExecutionLevel=requireAdministrator`). Otherwise, to request elevation in a new process, you need to use `ShellExecute/Ex()` instead with the `"runas"` verb.

Comment: thank you! this helped so much Im not sure why I was having such a hard time for a easy answer! Be safe kind sirs of the internet!